# Is there a way to make a browser window wider than 9999px?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, brave-browser

I'd like to be able to resize my screen to larger than 9999. Is this possible in modern browsers?

Comment: Yes, but only if your desktop actually is that big, or if your browser windows is “headless” - or if your window-manager allows it. On Windows and macOS the answer is “No” ].

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can, if your desktop is big enough:

Here's a photo of this very StackOverflow post, in Chrome, on Windows, that's **11,234px** wide:

(Yes, I'm just showing-off at this point)

[image]

Proof via `window.innerWidth`:

[image]